# Antlr error/exception handling

Tags: exception, antlr4

After doing some research online I found that this would be the way to catch the exceptions and output my own error messages. For some reason I still cannot seem to catch the errors. Below is the code for a class that overrides antlrs default error handling.

All I want to do is catch the exception from antlr and output to the screen that the syntax is incorrect in a java gui.

```
public class ExceptionErrorStrategy extends DefaultErrorStrategy {

@Override
public void recover(Parser recognizer, RecognitionException e) {
    throw e;
}

@Override
public void reportInputMismatch(Parser recognizer, InputMismatchException e) throws RecognitionException {
    String msg = "Input is mismatched " + getTokenErrorDisplay(e.getOffendingToken());
    msg += " expecting: "+e.getExpectedTokens().toString(recognizer.getTokenNames());
    RecognitionException ex = new RecognitionException(msg, recognizer, recognizer.getInputStream(), recognizer.getContext());
    ex.initCause(e);
    throw ex;
}

@Override
public void reportMissingToken(Parser recognizer) {
    beginErrorCondition(recognizer);
    Token t = recognizer.getCurrentToken();
    IntervalSet expecting = getExpectedTokens(recognizer);
    String msg = "Missing "+expecting.toString(recognizer.getTokenNames()) + " at " + getTokenErrorDisplay(t);
    throw new RecognitionException(msg, recognizer, recognizer.getInputStream(), recognizer.getContext());
}
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If all you want to do is report errors, then you are probably looking for the [`ANTLRErrorListener`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/ANTLRErrorListener.html) interface, not the [`AntlrErrorStrategy`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/ANTLRErrorStrategy.html) interface. The latter is geared towards actually modifying the behavior of the parser in response to errors, e.g. for automatic recovery attempts.

In ANTLRWorks 2, I use the following two classes as my primary implementations of this interface:

- [`SyntaxErrorListener`](https://github.com/sharwell/antlrworks2/blob/master/works.editor.antlr4/src/org/antlr/works/editor/antlr4/parsing/SyntaxErrorListener.java)
- [`DescriptiveErrorListener`](https://github.com/sharwell/antlrworks2/blob/master/works.editor.antlr4/src/org/antlr/works/editor/antlr4/parsing/DescriptiveErrorListener.java)

Comment: Do you know what method is actually spitting out the errors to my console?

Comment: Vague side question: How painful was it to add support for a new language in Netbeans?

Comment: @Sam Harwell Hi, I wonder if you have C# syntax for the DescriptiveErrorListener and SyntaxErrorListener above? I'm having trouble finding the syntax for the recognizer part of `public override void syntaxError<T>(Antlr4.Runtime.Recognizer<> recognizer,
    T offendingSymbol,...` Or a pointer to a C# example that collects errors into a string list instead of printing them to the console during parsing.Thank you